# How to redirect a request for DB1 to DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Suppose I have two databases named DB1 and DB2. In DB1, there is a table named Student, In DB2, there is a stored procedure named SP1. In SP1, I am selecting data of Student Table using below query :

Select *from DB1.dbo.Student.

I have more than 300 stored procedures having above said cross database communication. Now, I want to change my database from DB1 to DB3 that is identical to DB1 from data and schema perspective.
For this, I also have to modify all 300 stored procedures that are having fully-qualified database name. Now, the query will likely to be as follows :

Select *from DB3.dbo.Student

I don't want to change all stored procedure to point DB3 now, also don't want to change my queries written in stored procedure into dynamic SQL (I know this can be done by creating dynamic SQL).

Is it possible if We run DB1.dbo.Student, It will redirect to DB3.dbo.Student. Any intermediate layer or any SQL setting.

It'll be very big help for me. Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of your database renaming is to migrate a database, then why not rename the databases themselves?

e.g. say rename DB1 to DB1_old and then rename DB3 to DB1

Comment: This looks the easiest solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply script out all stored procedures using SQL Server script generator tool.  Then do a find replace on the script and find text ‘DB1.dbo.’ and replace with ‘DB3.dbo.’

In the future you might want to consider using synonyms to reference external tables then you would only have to update the synonyms instead of all of your procedures. Please see following MSDN article on synonyms:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx

Example use of synonym:

```
    USE [DB1]
    GO

    -- Create a synonym for table A located in DB2.
    CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[External_TableA] FOR [DB2].[dbo].[TableA]
    GO

    -- Synonym is pointing to TableA in DB2 , select statement will return data from DB2 tabla A.
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [External_TableA]

    GO

    -- Point the Synonym to same table but on DB3
    DROP SYNONYM [dbo].[External_TableA]
    CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[External_TableA] FOR [DB3].[dbo].[TableA]

    GO

    -- No update was needed on views or stored procedure.
    -- Synonym is pointing to TableA in DB3 , select statement will return data from DB3 tabla A.
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [External_TableA]
```

The follow query will generate the required DROP and CREATE script to remap your synonyms from the old database to the new database.

```
    DECLARE @oldDB NVARCHAR(100) = 'DB2';
    DECLARE @newDB NVARCHAR(100) = 'DB3';

    SELECT   'DROP SYNONYM [dbo].[' + name + ']' AS [Drop Script]
            ,'CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[' + name + '] FOR ' + REPLACE(base_object_name, @oldDB, @newDB) AS CreateScript
    FROM    sys.synonyms 
    ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Edmond.. I don't want to do Hard Code again. I need some way to call DB3 without changing my stored procedures.

Comment: Sadly, the only way that I am aware of to pass the DB as a parameter would be to re-write all of your procedures as dynamic sql which would be a far worse maintenance nightmare. I would still recommend the use of synonym. While not dynamic, you can update your synonyms without impacting on the rest of your stored procedures or views. It is also a lot easier to create code that can automatically drop and re-create your synonym. I have added an example to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

its better to use USE Keyword

use [database name you want to access]
Queries and stored procedure you want to use
GO

eg

```
use [db1]
select *from yourTableName
exec yourStoredProcedure parm1,parm2,....
Go
```